# Clarification about why what I'm doing in SSRS works(i.e I know it works but don't understand)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So I'm working with SSRS, and I'm basically migrating reports from Stored-procedures/ASPX pages to straight SSRS, which then displays the output in "report Manager" - about halfway there.

Well, the way I've been going about it(as instructed by boss) is to create these "fake" queries which are fed into the wizard.

They look like this:

```
exec [dbo].[prc_RPT_Respondent_Answer_By_PID]      
@BeginDate = '19001010',      
@EndDate  = '19001010',
@PID = 'test'
```

And the above goes into the "Query String" box( ie after  you'd Right-clk "Reports" --> "add new report" --> "next" ) .

But I am not sure why we create this dummy query.. Is it because then it would automatically add the Parameters (in the "Report Data" column on left) ?

Why not simply use "Query Builder" ?

Any help appreciatd .  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between your "fake query" and real query is the parameter values.  You need some parameter values to setup the report (i.e. obtain column definition etc), but your users will replace them at run time with the real values.

Comment: Ok I came back to study this again. so just to verify, when you say "obtain column definition etc"  .. this refers to SSRS' automatically designing it? Because otherwise you have to use the  "query builder" to design the query?  sorry if i'm askin 2 many Questions! i'm a newbie

Comment: Ssrs knows from your query which columns to expect back from your Stored Proc/SQL statement.  This allows you to drop columns relating to the resultset onto your report (and wizard will do it for you)

Comment: The other meta data returned to ssrs is the column types.   Different data types have different behaviour within your report and its expressions (i.e. date vs string vs int)

Answer (score 1):

In some situations calling a stored procedure with a SQL query can perform differently than calling it through the "Stored Procedure" option in SSRS. This usually has to do with the defaults of the connection.

On the other hand, it may just be a habit: "Don't change what isn't broken."